# Dynamically add DropDownList with Events to HTML table

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to setup a table that looks like the following:

| **Name** | **Email** | **CurrentUserGroup** | **ChangeUserGroup** |

Where the ChangeUserGroup column for each row has a DropDownList control with 3 options ( student, advisor, admin ) which, on the SelectedIndexChanged event, each row updates it's user's userGroup.

I had this working a few weeks ago, but never never commited the changes, and I lost them and CANNOT remember how I got this working.

This is how I'm currently building by table:

1. Page_Load calls BuildUserTableHtml() which creates the DropDownList in the table.

   ```
   private void buildUserTableHtml(List<User> users)
   {
   StringWriter htmlString = new StringWriter();
   using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(htmlString))
   {
       foreach(User user in users)
       {
           string name = user.firstName + " " + user.lastName;

           //tr
           writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);

           //td 1
           writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
           writer.Write(name);
           writer.RenderEndTag(); //td 1 end

           //td 2
           writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
           writer.Write(user.email);
           writer.RenderEndTag(); //td 2 end

           //td 3
           writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
           writer.Write(user.userGroup);
           writer.RenderEndTag(); //td 3 end

           //td
           HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
           DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
           ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("UerGroup", "0"));
           ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("User", "USER"));
           ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Advisor", "ADVISOR"));
           ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Admin", "ADMIN"));
           ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
           ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
           ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += userGroup_ItemChanged;
           cell.Controls.Add(ddl);
           cell.RenderControl(writer); // end td 4

           //td 5
           writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
           writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
           writer.AddAttribute("data-toggle", "tooltop");
           writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Title, "Delte User");
           writer.AddAttribute("href", "#");
           writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);
           writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
           writer.RenderEndTag();
           writer.RenderEndTag();
           writer.RenderEndTag(); //td 5 end

           writer.RenderEndTag(); //tr end

       }
   }
   userTable_PlcHldr.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlString.ToString() });
   }
   ```

userTable_PlcHldr is an .NET placeholder inside an already constructed table which is using a javascript plugin to make is searchable.

```
<table id="userTable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>User Group</th>
                        <th>Change</th>
                        <th>Delete User</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="userTable_PlcHldr" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

2. Change the selected value of the DropDownList - should fire userGroup_ItemChanged()

   ```
   protected void userGroup_ItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   UserGroup userGroup;
   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
   bool update = true;

   string value = ddl.SelectedValue;
   int ID = Int32.Parse(ddl.ID.Substring(1));
   switch (value)
   {
       case "ADMIN":
           userGroup = UserGroup.ADMIN;
           break;
       case "ADVISOR":
           userGroup = UserGroup.ADVISOR;
           break;
       case "USER":
           userGroup = UserGroup.USER;
           break;
       default:
           userGroup = UserGroup.DEFUALT;
           update = false;
           break;
   }
   try
   {
       if (update)
           UserGroups.UpdateUserGroup(ID, userGroup);

   } catch (Exception ex)
   {
       string error = ex.Message;
   }
   }
   ```

However, this code is not working. It correctly renders the controls on the page, but the SelectedItemChanged never fires. AutoPostBack is enabled. I think it's because the controls are not actually being added to the page correctly, and this the server does not see them.

Anyone know how else to do this?

Comment: We don't generally build up control HTML like that. Declare your controls on the ASPX markup and then bind the appropriate data to it. Use a repeater etc.

Comment: @mason Ok - I hadn't worked with repeaters before. I'll give that some research and report back if I figure it out or not.

Comment: If you're just now learning ASP.NET, why are you starting with Web Forms and not MVC?

Comment: I know some ASP.NET from my internship experience the past few summers, and the company used Web Forms not MVC. 

The project I'm working on is a semester long group project, and I was the only person with any experience with web applications. Instead of trying to teach myself and 3 other students MVC at the same time, I'm just using WebForms because I'm familiar with it.

Given more time and a team with more knowledge I would have used MVC.

Comment: MVC is easier to learn than Web Forms, it's faster, it's easier to get a decent architecture going, and Web Forms won't be included in the future of ASP.NET. I'd highly encourage you to [check out MVC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdO07KuPGqM) if it's not too late. With a little C# and HTML knowledge, it's easy to get up and running.

Comment: The project is due in two weeks, so it's too late to switch. I was able to get this working using an asp:repeater like you stated.

I will definitely learn MVC, as I know its a great design architecture to learn right now.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use grid view which very easy hardly takes 10 mins

Comment: @Krishna I dislike using GridView, it tries to abstract too much of the HTML away and ends up being messier than just using a repeater.

Comment: @mason agree, but it has lot of features which a fresher need to bother

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working using an asp:Repeater.

```
<table id="userTable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>User Group</th>
            <th>Change</th>
            <th>Delete User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("firstName").ToString() + " " + Eval("lastName").ToString() %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userGroup") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="userGroup_ItemChanged" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0"> <-UserGroup-> </asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="USER"> User </asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="ADVISOR"> Advisor </asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="ADMIN"> Admin </asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteUser" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-secondary" OnClick="deleteUser_Click">
                            <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete User"></span>
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("userID") %>' />
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then in my OnSelectedIndexChanged method userGroup_ItemChanged() I was able to get the hiddenID by doing the folloing:

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)ddl.NamingContainer;
HiddenField hiddenID = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("hiddenID");
int ID = int.Parse(hiddenID.Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

The Web Forms way is not to build up a string and append it to the control hierarchy. That's messy.

Instead, Web Forms will encourage you to bind your data to a control that already exists on the page, that was declared in the aspx.

I've prepared a working demo that you can drop into a new Web Forms application and it should *just work*:

Markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormsHelloWorld._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="UsersRepeater" ItemType="WebFormsHelloWorld.User">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Group</th>
                    <th>Change Group</th>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%#: Item.Name %></td>
                <td><%#: Item.Email %></td>
                <td><%#: Item.Group %></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="UsersNameHiddenField" Value="<%#: Item.Name %>" />
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Unnamed_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="--Select Item--" Value="SelectItem" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Admin" Value="Admin" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Advisor" Value="Advisor" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="User" Value="User" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

As you can see, we've declared our markup nicely in the ASPX page. Another cool thing we're taking advantage of is a strongly typed model. By setting the ItemType of the repeater, we can use `Item.Property` to access properties of our model object.

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebFormsHelloWorld
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                var users = new List<User>
                {
                    new User { Name = "Luke Skywalker", Email="luke@skywalker.com", Group = "Admin"},
                    new User { Name = "Han Solo", Email="han@solo.com", Group = "Advisor"},
                    new User { Name = "Leia Organa", Email="lea@alderan.com", Group = "User"},
                };

                UsersRepeater.DataSource = users;
                UsersRepeater.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void Unnamed_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList changedDropDownList = sender as DropDownList;
            var parentRow = changedDropDownList.Parent;
            var hiddenField = parentRow.FindControl("UsersNameHiddenField") as HiddenField;
            var userName = hiddenField.Value;
            Debug.WriteLine($"User {userName}, new group {changedDropDownList.SelectedValue}");
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I create a list of users in code. Likely for your real app you would get those from a repository somewhere. Then we bind them to the repeater when it's not a postback.

In the event handler for the dropdownlist, we get the name of the user we're modifying from a hidden field. We had to do some silly control hierarchy traversal to get that data, an annoying part of Web Forms. We cast the sender (the control that initated the event) to a dropdownlist and get it's current selected value. Finally, we write that to the debug console. In your application, you'd likely want to update the domain object in your repository.